# existence of mollifier

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Define $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{||x||^2 -1}}$ if $\|x\|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, and set $I=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f dm$.

Define $\phi=f/I$ and $\phi_\epsilon(x)={\epsilon}^{-n} \phi(x/\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$.

It is written in wikipedia that $\phi_\epsilon(x) \rightarrow \delta(x)$ in the space of Schwarz distribution, but how do I prove this?

(By the way, I know that $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi dm= 1$. )

Comment: Your $f $ is wrong. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, for $g\in L^2$,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g (x)\phi_\epsilon (x)dm\\
&=&\frac{1} {\epsilon^nI}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g (x)f (\frac {x}{\epsilon})dm\\
&=&\frac{1} {I}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g (\epsilon x)f (x)dm\\
&=&\frac{1} {I}\int_{\|x\|<1} g (\epsilon x)f (x)dm\\
&=&\frac{1} {I}\int_{\|x\|<1} g (0)f (x)dm+\frac{1} {I}\int_{\|x\|<1} [g(\epsilon x)-g (0)]f (x)dm\\
&=&g (0)+\frac{1} {I}\int_{\|x\|<1} [g(\epsilon x)-g (0)]f (x)dm.
\end{eqnarray}
It is easy to show that
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\|x\|<1} [g(\epsilon x)-g (0)]f (x)dm=0. $$
So
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g (x)\phi_\epsilon (x)dm=g(0). $$
Thus
$$ \phi_\epsilon (x)\to\delta(x) $$
in distribution.